# CREATE TABLE Failed. [3707] Syntax error,

Tags: sql, teradata

when i am trying to create a table like below

```
CREATE SET TABLE pp_scratch.HADOOP_FPTI_DASHBOARD ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
     id decimal(10,0) NOT NULL  GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1, MAXVALUE 999999999999, NO CYCLE)
      job_status VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      current_processing_hr VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      no_of_files_moved VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL)
PRIMARY INDEX  id;
```

> CREATE TABLE Failed.  [3707] Syntax error, expected something like a
>   name or a Unicode delimited identifier or a 'CYCLE' keyword between an
>   integer and ','.

could you please help what went wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There are no commas between the `Identity` options:

```
CREATE SET TABLE pp_scratch.HADOOP_FPTI_DASHBOARD ,NO FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
     id decimal(10,0) NOT NULL  
         GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1
                                       INCREMENT BY 1
                                       MAXVALUE 999999999999
                                       NO CYCLE),
      job_status VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      current_processing_hr VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
      no_of_files_moved VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL)
PRIMARY INDEX  id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The line defining `id` is missing a comma at the end:

```
 id decimal(10,0) NOT NULL
     GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1, MAXVALUE 999999999999, NO CYCLE),
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: no luck. Still i am geeting the same error

CREATE TABLE Failed.  [3707] Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or a 'CYCLE' keyword between an integer and ','.
Can you please help